# Reading streaming JSON in Groovy

Tags: java, json, groovy

We're trying to read streaming JSON data in Groovy (using JsonSlurper) but we only manage to do it by repeatedly parsing the source URL. What we would like to do is for it to be a push mechanism so that any time there is new content we get a callback. Is that possible? (if you have a solution in Java, that's fine too)

```
package json

import groovy.json.JsonParserType
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

class JsonParser {
    private static final String JSON_URL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes.csv%3Fs%3DHM-B.ST%26f%3Dsl1d1t1c1ohgv%26e%3D.csv'%20and%20columns%3D'symbol%2Cprice%2Cdate%2Ctime%2Cchange%2Ccol1%2Chigh%2Clow%2Ccol2'&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"

    static main(args) {
        def url = new URL(JSON_URL)
        def urlStream = null
        try {
            urlStream = url.openStream()
            def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().setType(JsonParserType.INDEX_OVERLAY)
            def jsonObj = jsonSlurper.parse(url)
            10.times {
                println jsonObj.query.created.toString()
                //println jsonObj.toString()
                jsonObj = jsonSlurper.parse(url)
                sleep(1000)
            }
        } finally {
            if (urlStream != null) urlStream.close()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use *push notifications* (aka. the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)), something needs to do the notifying. Since URLs don't notify, you've got to keep polling.

Threading considerations aside, here's a simple way to use polling with a callback.

```
import groovy.json.JsonParserType
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

final String JSON_URL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes.csv%3Fs%3DHM-B.ST%26f%3Dsl1d1t1c1ohgv%26e%3D.csv'%20and%20columns%3D'symbol%2Cprice%2Cdate%2Ctime%2Cchange%2Ccol1%2Chigh%2Clow%2Ccol2'&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"

poll(JSON_URL.toURL(), 5, 1000) { json ->
    println json
}

def poll(URL url, int iterations, int interval, Closure callback) {
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().setType(JsonParserType.INDEX_OVERLAY)
    def lastTimestamp = null

    iterations.times {
        def json = jsonSlurper.parse(url)
        def timestamp = json.query.results.row.time

        if(timestamp != lastTimestamp) callback(json)
        lastTimestamp = timestamp
        sleep(interval)
    }
}
```

The callback is a closure.

BONUS: The callback is only called when the data's timestamp has changed.